# Primefaces p:fileDownload inside p:treeTable doesn't work?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have such structure:

```
<p:treeTable value="#{cmpDocumentTree.root}" var="v" id="#{tableId}" selectionMode="single"
        selection="#{cmpDocumentTree.selectedNode}">
        <p:ajax event="expand" listener="#{cmpDocumentTree.onNodeExpand}" />
        <p:ajax event="collapse" listener="#{cmpDocumentTree.onNodeCollapse}" />
        <p:ajax event="select" listener="#{crudBean.edit(cmpDocumentTree.selectedNode.data)}"
            update=":#{formDialogUpdate}" oncomplete="#{formDialog}.show()" />
        <p:column headerText="Nazwa" sortBy="#{v.name}" style="min-width: 200px;">
            <h:outputText value="#{v.name}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Pliki" width="300">
            <ui:repeat var="_file1" value="#{v.files}">
                <h:commandLink value="#{_file1.originalFilename}">
                    <p:fileDownload
                        value="#{fileDownloadController.getFile(_file1.originalFilename, _file1.storedFilename, _file1.contentType)}" />
                </h:commandLink>
                <br />
            </ui:repeat>
        </p:column>
</p:treeTable>
```

But - p:fileDownload doesn't work. The fileDownloadController.getFile(...) method is not fired at all. 
When I put the same method inside p:dataTable, then it works perfectly.

**EDIT:**

v.files comes from ComDocument entity - it is relation one-to-many document-to-files.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "com_documents", schema = "public")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "COM_DOCUMENTS_SEQ", sequenceName = "COM_DOCUMENTS_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
public class ComDocument implements EntityInt, java.io.Serializable {
(...)
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "document", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<ComDocumentFile> files;

public void setFiles(List<ComDocumentFile> files) {
    this.files = files;
}

public List<ComDocumentFile> getFiles() {
    return files;
}
```

Could you help me? Thanks.

Comment: how is `v.files` getting populated, i.e. how does `v.getFiles` work?, show the code here please

Answer (score 3):

I've never had any luck with the FileDownload working inside an ajax request. I have not bothered to dig into the source as it is never a show stopper (and it really doesn't make sense to use it as an ajax request--you're getting a complete file, not updating a page).

The simple solution here is to make sure that your command button has "ajax=false"

```
<p:commandLink value="#{_file1.originalFilename}" ajax="false">
  <p:fileDownload
    value="#{fileDownloadController.getFile(_file1.originalFilename, file1.storedFilename,        _file1.contentType)}" />
</p:commandLink>
```

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileDownload.jsf

You'll notice all the examples have the ajax functionality disabled. If you're using h:commandButton for style I suggest using p:commandLink and styling it to be a button.

Best of luck, I'm pretty sure this will fix it. Also--make sure your "download objects" are final. You need to make sure that the data-source is referring to the same reference and not creating a new instance on each request.

Comment: I tried with p:commandLink, p:commandButton with ajax=false, but also without success. Strange is that the same structure in p:column but in p:dataTable (not p:treeTable) works fine. What do you mean - are final? With serial number of class?

Comment: No, I mean is the "getFile" method returning the same reference when called or does it return a reference to a new object? If it is working in the table there's a good chance it is a bug. You should hit the forums and ask--they are usually very quick to respond.

Comment: Ok, it looks like a bug indeed. I've already asked on pf forum but without any response. I've pinged the topic again. Hope they'll help. Thanks.